# Redirect subdomain to main domain in Joomla

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, joomla3.3

I need to redirect all subdomains of my website to the main domain starting with www:

I have tried to add this code to my .htaccess:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

but I have a redirect loop error.
What do you suggest?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rule will indeed cause redirect loop. Have it like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

---

If you want `demo.domain.com` to be redirected to `www.domain.com`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: HI anubhave, with this code all subdomains are redirect to main domain starting with www..., but I need that also:
domain.com (without www) is redirect to www.domain.com

How can I edit this code? Can you help me?
Thanks

Comment: Thanks anubhava, with this code I add www before my domain (Great!), but subdomain are not redirect. If, for example, I write **demo.domain.com** in my browser, the redirect url is **www.demo.domain.com** and not **www.domain.com**

Comment: So you want `demo.domain.com` to be redirected to `www.domain.com` instead of `www.demo.domain.com`? In that case check my rule in **EDIT** section above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this code in my .htaccess file at the root directory of the domain or subdomain
Redirect all requests from subdomain:

Redirect / http://www.example.com/

Redirect all requests from folder sub on the domain to the subdomain:

Redirect /sub http://sub.example.com/